# warning: 'assume_aligned' attribute directive ignored

Tags: c++, gcc

I just started with C++ and i think the best way is to look at source codes. I have code as follows in the header file.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define MYAPP_CACHE_ALIGNED_RETURN /* not supported */
#else
#define MYAPP_CACHE_ALIGNED_RETURN __attribute__((assume_aligned(64)))
#endif
```

I am using `gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)` and its quite old. I get this warning during compilation:

```
 warning: 'assume_aligned' attribute directiv e ignored [-Wattributes] –
```

How can I make the if statement more specific to fix the the warning during compilation?

Comment: What warning do you see?

Comment: @yugr `warning: 'assume_aligned' attribute directiv                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             e ignored [-Wattributes]`

Comment: Interesting [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608171/how-to-tell-gcc-that-a-pointer-argument-is-always-double-word-aligned reports `__builtin_assume_aligned` already supported 4 years ago. While your GCC is from 2015... it should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `assume_aligned` is not supported in RHEL's GCC (it hasn't been backported to upstream gcc-4_8-branch and also not available in Ubuntu 14.04's GCC 4.8.4 so that wouldn't be surprising).

To emit a more user-friendly diagnostics you can do an explicit check for GCC version in one of your headers:

```
#if __GNUC__ < 4 || (__GNUC__ == 4 && __GNUC_MINOR__ < 9)
#  warning "Your version of GCC does not support 'assume_aligned' attribute"
#endif
```

But this may not work if your distro vendor has back-ported `assume_aligned` from upstream (which is not the case for RedHat and Ubuntu but who knows about other distros). The most robust way to check this would be to do a build-time test in `configure` script or in `Makefile`:

```
CFLAGS += $(shell echo 'void* my_alloc1() __attribute__((assume_aligned(16)));' | gcc -x c - -c -o /dev/null -Werror && echo -DHAS_ASSUME_ALIGNED)
```

This will add `HAS_ASSUME_ALIGNED` to predefined macro if the attribute is supported by compiler.

Note that you can achieve similar effect with __builtin_assume_aligned function:

```
void foo() {
  double *p = func_that_misses_assume_align();
  p = __builtin_assume_aligned(p, 128);
  ...
}
```

Comment: then how do i check if `assume_aligned` is supported in the header files.

Comment: @user2650277 Thanks, fixed.