# How to tell gcc that the data pointed to by a pointer will always be aligned?

Tags: c, gcc, memory, avx

In my program (written in plain C) I have a structure which holds data prepared to be transformed by vectorized (AVX only) radix-2 2D fast fourier transform. The structure looks like this:

```
struct data {
    double complex *data;
    unsigned int width;
    unsigned int height;
    unsigned int stride;
};
```

Now I need to load data from memory as fast as possible. As far as I know there exists unaligned and aligned load to ymm registers (vmovapd and vmovupd instructions) and I would like the program to use the aligned version as its faster.

So far I use roughly similar construction for all operations over the array. This example is part of program when data and filter are both already transformed to frequency domain and the filter is applied to data by element by element multiplication.

```
union m256d {
    __m256d reg;
    double d[4];

};

struct data *data, *filter;
/* Load data and filter here, both have the same width, height and stride. */

unsigned int stride = data->stride;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i<data->height; i++) {
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j<data->width; j+=4) {
        union m256d a[2];
        union m256d b[2];
        union m256d r[2];

        memcpy(a, &(  data->data[i*stride+j]), 2*sizeof(*a));
        memcpy(b, &(filter->data[i*stride+j]), 2*sizeof(*b));

        r[0].reg = _mm256_mul_pd(a[0].reg, b[0].reg);
        r[1].reg = _mm256_mul_pd(a[1].reg, b[1].reg);

        memcpy(&(data->data[i*stride+j]), r, 2*sizeof(*r));
    }
}
```

As expected memcpy calls are optimized. However after observation gcc translates memcpy either to two vmovupd instructions or to bunch of movq instructions which load data to guaranteedly aligned place on stack and then two vmovapd instructions which load it to ymm registers. This behavior depends whether the memcpy prototype is defined or not (if it is defined then gcc uses movq and vmovapd).

I am able to ensure that the data in memory are aligned but I am not sure how to tell gcc that it can just use movapd instructions to load data from memory straight to ymm registers. I strongly suspect that gcc does not know the fact that data pointed by `&(data->data[i*stride+j])` are always aligned.

Is there any option how to tell gcc that the data pointed to by a pointer will always be aligned?

Comment: Have you thought about writing the important parts of this in assembly?

Comment: The important things are written with intel intrinsics which basically means that gcc translates each call like `_mm256_mul_pd(a[0].reg, b[0].reg);` to one vector instruction. I have issue with interconnecting the important parts with the rest. That means loading data from memory. If I am not mistaken, I wasn't able to do it in optimal way which as far as I know should be just two vmovapd instructions.

Comment: Don't use `memcpy`? Write your own function with the appropriate types. I don't even see how this is related to the C language as such.

Comment: @Olaf Oh, I really didn't think about that. Thank you for suggestion, that sounds like a simple solution to this problem, so I'll definitely try it.

Comment: Indeed, even if C had a way to declare the alignment of a pointer target, it seems unreasonably hopeful that GCC would choose to inline a `memcpy()` implementation that happens to be optimized exactly the way you want.

Comment: Could you use _mm256_load_pd instead of memcpy? _mm256_load_pd seems to do a VMOVAPD instruction.

Comment: `void * __builtin_assume_aligned (const void *EXP,
          size_t ALIGN, ...)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`vmovupd` is exactly as fast as `vmovapd` when the data is in fact aligned at runtime.  The only difference is that `vmovapd` faults when the data isn't aligned.  (See optimization links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki, especially [Agner Fog's optimization and microarch pdfs](http://agner.org/optimize/), and Intel's [optimization manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm#optimization).

You only have a problem if it ever uses multiple instructions instead of one.

---

Since you're using Intel intrinsics for `_mm256_mul_pd`, **use load/store intrinsics instead of memcpy!**  See the [sse](/questions/tagged/sse) tag wiki for intrinsics guides and more.

```
// Hoist this outside the loop,
// mostly for readability; should optimize fine either way.
// Probably only aliasing-safe to use these pointers with _mm256_load/store (which alias anything)
// unless C allows `double*` to alias `double complex*`
const double *flat_filt = (const double*)filter->data;
      double *flat_data =       (double*)data->data;

for (...) {
    //union m256d a[2];
    //union m256d b[2];
    //union m256d r[2];

       //memcpy(a, &(  data->data[i*stride+j]), 2*sizeof(*a));
    __m256d a0 = _mm256_load_pd(0 + &flat_data[i*stride+j]);
    __m256d a1 = _mm256_load_pd(4 + &flat_data[i*stride+j]);
       //memcpy(b, &(filter->data[i*stride+j]), 2*sizeof(*b));
    __m256d b0 = _mm256_load_pd(0 + &flat_filt[i*stride+j]);
    __m256d b1 = _mm256_load_pd(4 + &flat_filt[i*stride+j]);
       // +4 doubles = +32 bytes = 1 YMM vector = +2 double complex

    __m256d r0 = _mm256_mul_pd(a0, b0);
    __m256d r1 = _mm256_mul_pd(a1, b1);

       // memcpy(&(data->data[i*stride+j]), r, 2*sizeof(*r));
    _mm256_store_pd(0 + &flat_data[i*stride+j], r0);
    _mm256_store_pd(4 + &flat_data[i*stride+j], r1);
}
```

If you wanted an unaligned load/store, you'd use `_mm256_loadu_pd` / `storeu`.

Or you could have just cast your `double complex*` to a `__m256d*` and dereferenced that directly.  In GCC, that's equivalent to an aligned-load intrinsic.  But the usual convention is to use load/store intrinsics.

---

To answer the title question, though, you can help gcc auto-vectorize by telling it when a pointer is guaranteed to be aligned:

```
data = __builtin_assume_aligned(data, 64);
```

In C++, you need to cast the result, but in C `void*` is freely castable.

See [How to tell GCC that a pointer argument is always double-word-aligned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608171/how-to-tell-gcc-that-a-pointer-argument-is-always-double-word-aligned)  and  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html.

This is of course specific to GNU C/C++ dialects (clang, gcc, icc), not portable to MSVC or other compilers that don't support GNU extensions.

---

> So far I use roughly similar construction for all operations over the array.

Looping over the array multiple times is usually worse than doing as much as possible in a single pass.  Even if it all stays hot in L1D, just the extra load and store instructions are a bottleneck compared to doing more while your data is in registers.

Answer (score 0):

As Olaf pointed it is possible to write appropriate load and save functions. So now the code translates nicely to two vmovapd instructions on load and two vmovapd on save.

```
static inline void mload(union m256d t[2], double complex *f)
{
    t[0].reg = _mm256_load_pd((double *)f);
    t[1].reg = _mm256_load_pd((double *)(f+2));
}

static inline void msave(union m256d f[2], double complex *t)
{
    _mm256_store_pd((double *)t, f[0].reg);
    _mm256_store_pd((double *)(t+2), f[1].reg);
}

unsigned int stride = data->stride;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i<data->height; i++) {
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j<data->width; j+=4) {
        union m256d a[2];
        union m256d b[2];
        union m256d r[2];

        mload(a, &(  data->data[i*stride+j]));
        mload(b, &(filter->data[i*stride+j]));

        r[0].reg = _mm256_mul_pd(a[0].reg, b[0].reg);
        r[1].reg = _mm256_mul_pd(a[1].reg, b[1].reg);

        msave(r, &(data->data[i*stride+j]));
    }
}
```