# Fast AND operation on bit arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, char, bitarray, bitwise-and

What can be a faster algorithm for doing bitwise AND operation on large bit-arrays? I have implemented bit-array in C++ using a char array. For now, I am iterating over each byte and performing AND operation.

```
void ANDoperation(char* A, char* B){
  for (int i=0; i<(array_size/8 +1); i++ ){
    A[i] &= B[i];
  }
}
```

For K arrays, I am executing this function iteratively K-1 times.

Comment: What are your requirements regarding to "speed" and "efficiency"? Is this measured to be a primary (top-two) bottleneck of your program? Have you done your measurement and benchmarking with compiler optimizations enabled?

Comment: this is the fastest way. The compiler will automatically vectorize the loop for you so it won't even loop over each `char`

Comment: If you know that your arrays are properly aligned, and they're longer than 2 or 4 bytes, you can perform the AND in blocks of `uint16_t`, `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` (at the cost of substantially more complex code).

Comment: Your code might access beyond arrays in special cases or alternatively only work on a fraction of the total arrays. In that case I would first discuss fixing, before discussing optimising. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah. I have tried with O2 optimisation. This is the bottleneck. The bit array size in my case is > 10^6.

Comment: Thanks @DaveM. Looks like I should try uint64_t array. That should help.

Comment: what's array_size? 
When posting code samples, please provide the minimal example that will work if copied     https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `O2` may not turn on vectorization. Try `O3`, and consider making your pointers _restricted_. Without `restrict`, vectorization might be avoided. It may be also good idea to align arrays properly for vectorization (e.g., at 64-bit boundary for AVX-512). This question may be relevant: [How to tell GCC that a pointer argument is always double-word-aligned?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9608171/580083) How do you measure it's a bottleneck? 10^6 is a very small array.

Comment: Compare these versions here: https://godbolt.org/z/hedNBo. You can observe that, in the second case, there is a minimum amount of instructions in the loop (1x vector-register load, 1x and, 1x store).

Comment: @DaveM. that's not the fastest way, and definitely not "substantially more complex". The fastest way is to use SIMD (which is far more complex than `uint64_t*`), but [compilers will automatically do that for you even if you pass a char array](https://godbolt.org/z/XZELfA). Look at the `vpand` instructions there

Comment: Adding __ restrict __ to the parameters is the key to getting the compiler to auto-vectorize.

Comment: In my tests, the above code with restrict made the compiler use the YMM registers and handle 512 bits per AND instruction. Whereas the std::bitset version compiled down to using normal registers and only did 64-bits per AND instruction.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to go for a more C++-ish way, I would suggest you using [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) in a following manner:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

int main()  {
    std::bitset<3> v1(0b110);
    std::bitset<3> v2(0b011);

    v1 &= v2;

    std::cout << v1.to_string() << std::endl; // 010

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:13,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:13,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:13,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:13),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cbitset%3E%0A%0Aint+main()++%7B%0A++++std::bitset%3C3%3E+v1(0b110)%3B%0A++++std::bitset%3C3%3E+v2(0b011)%3B%0A%0A++++v1+%26%3D+v2%3B%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+v1.to_string()+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:52.637075718015666,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g91,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B14+-O3',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.1+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:37.5,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+9.1',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:47.362924281984334,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

or as [@AndrewBainbridge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/66088/andrew-bainbridge) suggested:

```cpp
void and_operation(std::bitset<3000>& v1, std::bitset<3000> const& v2) {
    v1 &= v2;
}
```

Comment: you didn't specify `-O3` so no optimization is done. But even with optimization this will result very bad performance because `std::vector<bool>` is a specialization which operates on bit. Just check the output assembly you'll see no vectorization is done

Comment: The Demo link (to a Godbolt session) shows that the compiler evaluated the AND at compile time. Here's a better session: https://godbolt.org/z/XN5k5u

Comment: The length of the bitset needs to be large, otherwise the compiler does the whole array in a single instruction. I set the length to 3000 in my example. The resulting code is a loop that processes 64 bits per iteration.

Comment: @AndrewBainbridge yes, you are right. I put 3 only as an example but will put 3000. Thank you

Comment: Also, "in your case" might be better as "in Andrew's case", since we've already got two commenters.